# Error with pstree

Tags: pstricks, pst-tree

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics,graphicx}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node,pst-tree}
\begin{document}
\pstree[levelsep=35pt]{\Tcircle{10}}
{
\Tcircle{11} \Tcircle{21}
}
\end{document}
```

Why the error:

> ! Undefined control sequence.
>    \c@lor@to@ps 
>                                 l.5 \pstree[levelsep=35pt]{\Tcircle{10}}
>                                            ?

I compile with latexmk if that makes any difference:

[image]

Comment: @ptrcao: I don't get any error. Please, add `\listfiles` in front of the code and show the output of this command that you easily find in the `.log` file.

Comment: @ptrcao --- Jasper Loy is correct, the problem is caused by using `pdflatex`, which does not work with `pstricks`. Try using `latexmk -pdfdvi` in place of `latexmk`.

Comment: @Jasper --- the [manual](http://www.phys.psu.edu/~collins/software/latexmk-jcc/latexmk-424.pdf) says it uses `dvipdf` by default, and I think that uses ghostscript and `dvips`. It works fine on my system, but maybe `-pdfps` is a safer option.

Comment: @egreg Just clarifying your instructions; where does "\listfiles" go in the code exactly?  Before \documentclass{article} or after \documentclass{article} but before \begin{document}, or after \begin{document} but before all the rest of the code?

Answer (score 1):

You have several possibilities to run PostScript related code with `pdflatex`:

- run `xelatex` instead of `latexmk`, which is the easiest way.
- use package `auto-pst-pdf` and add the optional argument `-shell-escape` to the `pdflatex` call
- instead of `pdflatex` run `latex`

see also: http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=pdf/pdfoutput

Comment: @Herbert : I need latexmk for my bibliography, so it will run processors the correct number of times.  I also want my output as a pdf file.  Where does this leave me?

Comment: @ptrcao then use package `auto-pst-pdf` and add the option  `-shell-escape` to the pdflatex call.

Comment: I'm still relatively new to Latex, would you be so kind as to explicitly spell out the steps involved in adding the -shell-escape option?  I use TexWorks.

Comment: I got this error: "! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \c@lor@to@ps 
                             
l.8 \pstree[levelsep=35pt]{\Tcircle{10}}
                                        
?"   What now?