# psframe " Undefined control sequence"

Tags: pstricks

I am trying to create a book cover by using PSTricks. I follow the source from here :http://tug.org/pracjourn/2007-1/robbers/robbers.pdf (page 22). When I compile, it annouces the error that :

```
! Undefined control sequence.
 \c@lor@to@ps 

l.29 ...tyle=solid,fillcolor=Maroon](0,0)(13.24,9)

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

And the error is in fact at the line :

```
\psframe[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=Maroon](0,0)(13.24,9)
```

Please tell me what I should do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're probably using `pstricks` with `pdflatex`.

Comment: See [<recently read> \c@lor@to@ps](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68870/recently-read-clortops) or [Error with pstree](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19007/error-with-pstree). Please tell us if the answers there helped, we should close this as a duplicate.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I have changed and it does not annouce the error there any more. However, it now annouced the error at the box 
\sbox\IBox{\includegraphics[height=9in]{grass3.jpg}}.
 It said that 
"Cannot determine size of graphic in grass3.jpg". How I can correct it then? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @9999 Please update the question according to your latest comment.